# Team lunch - I have food preferences the venue can't accommodate

Tags: team-building, lunch

I am a vegetarian (and also I don't drink). Our manager takes the team out to lunch, say, once every quarter.

This time they are planning to go to a restaurant that has no vegetarian options. Monetary value is not a concern here, but I find it awkward to remind them that I am a vegetarian every time.

I am planning to either skip the event or to ask for a change of venue.

Would it be considered rude to do either of these? Which one would be the lesser evil? Or is there an alternative way that I can handle this situation?

Comment: This other question addresses yours, I believe: https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/57436/adjusting-to-a-team-with-conflicting-socialisation-preferences-for-a-group-dinne

Comment: @GreenMatt I also think it does. Dexter, does that post help or is your situation different somehow? If it's different, please edit your post to explain how so.

Comment: A small difference between the questions is that in this question, the restaurant doesn't have a vegetarian option at all. Some of the answers still apply though.

Comment: What is the location? In most countries the idea of not-having veggie option is insane, and may just not be on whatever menu OP saw. I would first talk to the boss and ask if they have the veggie option somewhere (or just call the place yourself). Even if it's off the card, any restaurant worth it salt will serve a veggie option.

Comment: My manager seems to be a good person but is kind of very forgetful. The last time we went, I had to prompt before the venue was decided that I am a vegetarian. I kind of feel bad having to bring this up every time.

Comment: @Dexter Assuming your manager is a sane person with just a problem about remembering things, it will be happy to be reminded every time it is needed. In the end, being a vegetarian is something personal to you so I think the right approach is to appreciate who remembers but have no hesitation to say it every time it is needed.

Comment: @Dexter Perfectly reasonable to send a reminder, especially if it's only quarterly. I do this for my group and they are always very nice about providing a vegetarian meal for me, I just work it into the planning discussion... "Sure, I can attend xyz time, as long as there's a vegetarian option, please, thanks!"

Comment: Short of having lunch at a butcher shop, I can't see how they'd have meat in *everything* served and couldn't accommodate in some way (e.g. chicken Cesar salad without the chicken). They probably at the very least have fries or chips+salsa (I know it's not a full meal, but something to much on during the event and then you can go have a real meal after). I'm just having trouble imagining a meat-only menu...(1/2)

Comment: (2/2) but if really is an all-meat menu (or if all they have is fries) then I'd say it's completely fair to ask for a change in venue.

Comment: I can't see a country listed on your question, but in some, what you're describing could be considered discrimination (and would probably come up as part of a case of discrimination if something else was the main complaint). If it's just forgetfulness, that's sort of excusable, but an inclusive boss should be asking "hey, I thought we would try X this time around, what do you think?" before booking the venue.

Comment: @RalphBolton *but in some, what you're describing could be considered discrimination* That's fascinating. Can you cite some examples of where this would (legally) be considered discrimination?

Comment: I think the size of the team is an important factor here and would be worth mentioning.  If it's a small team accommodating everyone can be done fairly easily but as the number of people increase accommodating everyone's dietary preferences and restrictions becomes a nearly impossible task.

Comment: If part of your job is going out to lunch with the boss, and going out to lunch means eating meat, then it's discrimination against Hindus and a few other religions. It probably also discriminates against Muslims and Orthodox Jews unless the place serves halal or kosher.

Comment: It would seem really weird to not accomodate a vegetarian.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Don't ask to change the venue directly. Presumably this lunch is on the company's dime,  it might look ungrateful.

You can subtly/indirectly seek a change of venue if you politely decline and highlight the lack of vegetarian option as your reason.  "I'd love to go but they don't seem to have any vegetarian option on the menu so I'm afraid, in this instance, I'll have to pass".

My guess is, if your company are good enough employers to have regular team lunches, this was most likely an oversight on their part - somebody forgot you are vegetarian or maybe didn't know in the first place if all the other venues had suitable meal choices.  Upon receiving your reply, I'd imagine they will apologise profusely and change the venue if possible.  (In the event that the venue can't be changed, I don't think skipping will be a problem)

*Of course, if the meeting is a mandatory work meeting, then you'd need to approach this a little differently*

Comment: But first, make sure that the restaurant indeed doesn't have a vegetarian option on the menu, because if it does, your manager is sure to bring it up. If on the other hand, you don't like any of the vegetarian options it has on the menu, say that instead.

Comment: To take it one step further, don't just check the menu: call the restaurant and tell them what party you will be coming with (company lunch from X Inc and the date), and ask if they have or can make something _off the menu_. When reserving, your team may have had the foresight to ask, and the restaurant may have been secretly accommodating.

Comment: @msanford I think that could probably be an Answer in its own right.

Comment: _"Presumably this lunch is on the company's dime, it might look ungrateful."_ Why on earth would you be grateful for a lunch where you can't eat anything?

Comment: This is the least intrusive answer. You won't come off as being egocentrical, just simply acting by your beliefs. No one in their right mind will be displeased with you for this reason...

Answer (score 84):

To take it one step further, don't just check the menu: call the restaurant and tell them what party you will be coming with (company lunch from X Inc and the date) and ask if they have or can make something off the menu.

When reserving, your team may have had the foresight to ask, and the restaurant may have been secretly accommodating. You'll also be able to suss out what kind of options they might be able to offer by speaking to them.

That has been my experience.

Comment: +1 - I've done exactly that. I asked this in a Greek restaurant where every option of the menu was meat centered. It turned out, our server, who happened to be the owner of the establishment, was a vegan, and was very happy to help. They brought out the most amazing vegan Greek pasta I have ever had. Only good things can come from asking.

Comment: @AndreasGrapentin This *might* be culture-dependent, but most places I've seen are happy to accomodate you with a vegetarian meal, disregardless of the owner being vegan/vegetarian or not. Whether it's tasty or not is another matter.

Comment: Extra benefit is that this will show the restaurant the demand for vegetarian items, and eventually they might add some to the menu.

Comment: The thing is you might get a positive answer while actually the vegetarian options are some normal ones with meat removed, or side dishes turned into main courses, ... not having any vegetarian option on the menu is at least an orange flag from where I see it.

Comment: Would surprise me if they really don't have any food suited for vegetarians - say a big salad - Vegan puts more serious limits

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem that your own team is routinely completely ignoring your needs and wants when they organise something that should be for everyone.

Comment: Every time I've been to a restaurant where they didn't have a vegetarian option on the menu, we asked and they could always make something. I do not agree with @LightnessRaceswithMonica that the team is ignoring his needs. OP follows a special diet and there are plenty of ways to deal with the issues that might arise with this diet, rather than just saying "you other 19 people are bullying me"

Comment: @Caroline If the vegetarian dietary requirement has been made every single time the work lunch was arranged, and the work lunch happens four times a year, and the requirement is _still_ being ignored to the point that the work lunch is arranged at a restaurant that does not cater for these dietary requirements at all, and no arrangements have been made, then, yes, the other 19 people (or, at the very least, the organiser) is bullying the OP. Yes, the OP can find a way to work around it. But, no, **they shouldn't have to** and frankly I find this to be obvious. This is basic employee care.

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica "This time" doesn't indicate at all that the requirement is ignored routinely. Also, there is a chance the organizer simply forgot about the requirement of one person. I have no idea how big the team is, but if it's a larger one, I very much understand not being able to remember every members dietary requirements. I do not find it very obvious and I do think the OP should put in some effort as well rather than just saying "the others are the issue". For all we know the role of organizer switches every lunch, or a different member gets to pick a restaurant every time.

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica Also, there's no indication that "no other arrangements have been made". OP didn't ask the organizer yet, perhaps the organizer did make arrangements and simply forgot to tell OP.

Comment: @Caroline Granted, but if we take the question at face value, that is not the case. Also it really shouldn't be "forgot" by this point. It should a part of the process. This isn't even difficult! Literally every single group meal event I've _ever_ been involved in (in my adult life) has asked for dietary requirements. It's completely and utterly prevalent. How anyone can forget to arrange it or to make clear that it's been arranged is beyond me.

Comment: @FreeMan Dietary requirements clearly stated for a work lunch, and "I don't like the colour red but someone keeps wearing it" are _entirely_ different things. Being a vegetarian doesn't make you "a self-centered, self-righteous little snowflake", nor is it "a weird proclivity". You're being utterly ridiculous.

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica From my vegetarian experience, I disagree with you. Non-vegetarians often assume that there will be a suitable vegetarian option everywhere--they don't realize that you need to check the menu every time. (They also often don't even realize that certain items don't qualify as vegetarian.) On top of that, there are a lot of moving pieces in planning a large group, so it's not surprising when things get missed--next month they may forget and cross schedule against Jordan's weekly appointment.

Comment: @user3067860 I can completely believe not thinking about it the first time, if it's a bunch of friends meeting up. Even the second time, _maybe_. But not only is this a regular event for the OP, but it's attached to a workplace. Forgetting that one of your team members is a vegetarian when you're on, say, the fifth or sixth regular meetup and you've already forgotten every other time as well is just inexcusable.

Comment: @FreeMan doesn't sound like OP wants to stop *everyone* from eating meat. Reasonable or not it's common enough that it should be accounted for when organizing a meal for a group of people.

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica I'm not even saying they forgot that the OP is vegetarian. Just that they didn't consider that they need to check the menu specifically for vegetarian options. (But really--my friends, my coworkers, and my family have all legitimately forgotten to provide vege options for me, and I've been vegetarian for 20+ years now. I guess it's possible that everyone just really hates me...)

Comment: @user3067860 That must be it :P

Comment: One should consider how the mind works.  If you are not vegetarian, you never think about this when choosing a restaurant, so that's the default thing your brain does.  If you have gone to zillions of restaurants and there is always a vegetarian option when a vegetarian is present, that reinforces the "this situation is always covered" thing and your brain will move back to "this is a thing to ignore, I'm not spending time on it".  Four times a year is really infrequent, which also tends to make it a "don't spend effort on this, you don't do it often enough" thing.  All unconscious.

Answer (score 10):

Ask the venue for a simple salad or something equivalent even if it is not on the menu. Restaurants agree to this, as long as they can charge you for some standard menu item. I have done this multiple times in different places due to a family member's food sensitivities.

It would seem unreasonable to try and change everything for your food preference when the event is about team building. Focus on the building and have a nice meal before you go and then just snack there on a small substitute meal.

Comment: “It would seem unreasonable to try and change everything for your food preference when the event is about team building.” I disagree. If the OP goes into this event with some (not unreasonable!) resentment because the company ignored their dietary restrictions, they’re not going to be very amenable to the team building the company is trying to accomplish. It’s very much in the company’s interest to make sure the lunch is held at a venue where everyone can at least find something to eat. (Even better, obviously, if everyone is actually *happy* with the choice of restaurant.)

Comment: That being said, it’s not totally clear whether the company is ignoring OP’s restrictions or is just unaware of them.

Answer (score 3):

Which is more important to you, food or being with the team? (Either is okay I think but your strategy will change).

> If food is important

Which means the quality of food you eat has to be great and as per your taste, then you can request a change in menu or politely decline like others have answered.

> If being with the team is important

Then you just compromise on "tasty meal" and order some salad or ask something to be made which is vegetarian. It may not taste great but it will serve your hunger.  I have been to many restaurants in several places around the world where one would think that it is impossible to have anything vegetarian, but on request they will always make something for you. You cannot be too picky but you still get to eat with the team without requesting a change.

Of course if you are afraid and are particular about your food not accidentally touching with meat in the kitchen, then it is best to avoid eating "vegetarian" food anywhere outside. No can guarantee what happens in the kitchen!

Answer (score 2):

I do face the same situation sometimes. I'd go to lunch out, enjoy the companion, come back and have my lunch the same as I usually do.

If we need special needs, we better take our self to take care of us. None of the others should change their plans for us. A kind request could be an option but in these kinda workplace matters, better to stay away from changing other's plans.

Don't miss the lunch, these social, teambuilding events are essential to staying relay on your job if you are not working remotely.

Comment: This is a reasonable accommodation to do. Forcing others to eat on vegan only restaurant is actually the problem.

Comment: @AnishSheela Nobody would reasonably expect them to switch to a vegan only restaurant. Furthermore I don't see why this is more of a problem than the other way round. Omnivores can eat vegan foods, too. They might be prejuidiced, but this is their issue and therefor their responsibility to take care of.

Comment: We can ask for changes and usually, it's not a matter in family life, but when we are in our workplace, we better act in a professional way, better not to interrupt other's plans. 

Apparently the company seems like not acted in a professional way, as usual, an HR manager would not arrange meat only locations or total vegan rather selecting a place that can cater to most of the categories.

Comment: This sort of passive response is quite dangerous. So you don't want to "change others' plans". What about _your_ plans? What about _your_ ability to join in? You're letting discrimination slide and that's not okay.

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica Does intent not matter? Do you think the company is *deliberately* discriminating against this person or is it far more likely this was an unintentional oversight?

Comment: @SoraPro Intent does make some difference, and since we cannot gauge it remotely, I'll leave that one alone. But, still, if after five or six goes you're still not getting that somebody on your work team is a vegetarian, regardless of your intent you need to buck up your ideas a bit.

Comment: Please note that this is a new contributor and avoid downvote brigading this.  This is a valid way that a person who wants to be completely nonconfrontational could approach it (remember that people are different in their social choices as well as dietary).  It could be significantly more memorable for the organizer to have the experience of "I chose a restaurant that had no vegetarian option and one person came and didn't eat" than "someone reminded me they were vegetarian last time" (which is a much less odd occurrence, more forgettable), which might solve the problem in the future.

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica what evidence is there to suggest this has happened "five or six" times? The language used in the OP seems to imply this is the first time a restaurant was selected where his needs are not being met. I don't understand why speculation beyond that is necessary.

Comment: @SoraPro I'm extrapolating a bit, I concede, but _"I find it awkward to remind them that I am a vegetarian every time"_ seems pretty clear.

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica Based on the previous context, that seems to suggest OP had assumed he would not have to mention this again since he had already mentioned it before their last outing. It is not "pretty clear" that a restaurant without vegetarian options was selected prior to this incident. Whenever OPs manager was consciously aware of OPs vegetarian diet, he catered to it. The issue here is the "awkwardness" of having to remind his manager every time. Trying to attribute malice to anyone is not helpful here.

Comment: @msouth:- Thank you.

Lightness & SoraPro:-Facts are true. 

Totally this shows a lack of week experience of an HR management person. They learn these things while their studies.
He can make them notice that they haven't think about veggie people, he can have something else for lunch, but what I was saying was

I feel as a vegetarian I should not bother other nonveg's plans, but I should keep in my mind they didn't pay attention about me too. Remind them might works.

But the most important thing is, these kind of social events in working places are not good to be missed for any cost

Comment: @SoraPro It is helpful if that's what's going on. I don't understand why you're so insistent on defending this behaviour.

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica What "behavior"? I've read your comments in this thread and you seem hellbent on blaming someone for a simple oversight. You are even going as far as to make assumptions without any evidence at all. That is destructive advice, not helpful.

Comment: @SoraPro And you're missing the entire point that _it is not a "simple" oversight_. Sorry, but if you don't get it by now, I can't explain it to you. Let's move on.

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica I do get it. Either it was done deliberately or it was an accident. I have read nothing in the original post that indicates this was done for deliberate or nefarious reasons. My faith in humans treating each other with decency, especially in a professional environment, is apparently far higher than yours.

Comment: @SoraPro I didn't say it was done for deliberate or nefarious reasons (in fact I literally said we cannot gauge intent remotely). I said that, _regardless_ of the reasons, even if they're sheer ignorance/incompetence, after five or six times this is completely unacceptable and should not be approached so passively. As I said, let's move on; this is not a constructive conversation any more.

Answer (score 2):

> I find it awkward to prompt that I am a vegetarian every time

So, it seems they're already very aware you're a vegetarian.

> I am planning to either skip the event or to ask for a change of venue

Yes, ask for a change of venue, with a smile, citing the reason.

They've most likely simply not realised the place has no options, or they've somehow forgotten you're a vegetarian in the (perhaps hasty) choice of place.

You're not *in any way* the one who has to worry about being rude here. It's a **team** lunch - everyone in the team should be catered for, full stop.

Comment: To ask for the entire team to change venue just for you strikes me as a bit selfish. It's a rule of life that You Can't Please Everyone. If you think you can, you're already f*ed.

Comment: "You can't please everyone" is not really an acceptable excuse to short one subset (e.g. vegetarians) every time, or to not check for vegetarian >options<, which would still allow the non-vegetarians to have their non-vegetarian options as well. Standing up in that instance cannot possibly be considered selfish in any reasonable team.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't feel bad for bringing up the issue, in fact, it's somewhat insulting that they either forget your dietary needs or worst, disregard them entierly.

**You should approach the issue respectfully but firmly and ask for a change of vanue**. Remind the organizer that you are a vegetarian and that the place they chose has no vegetarian options<sup>*</sup>. Also, you should also remind them that this is not the first time that the issue has come up (if it's the case) and that you would really appreciate it if the next time they will remember this and will choose a place that can accommodate your dietary needs from the start.

You should do it as fast as possible, don't wait until the last minute, when it may be hard to make any changes, give enough time in advance to make the change.

This lunch is paid for by the company and is part of your job, even if it's not mandatory participation, it's a bonding activity for the team and excluding people from it because of their dietary needs is the exact opposite of the desired result. A meal supplied by the company should accommodate all the workers and be inclusive.

<sup>* - unless it's the case, as some suggested that the organizer has made arrangements to have a vegetarian option beforehand. In any case, it's not your job to make sure that the lunch is inclusive to all, it's the responsibility of the organizer.</sup>